# Could someone explain these Haskell functions to me?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, haskell

I've dabbled with Haskell in the past, and recently got back into it seriously, and I'm reading real world haskell. Some of the examples they've shone, I've yet to understand. Such at this one:

```
myLength []     = 0
myLength (x:xs) = 1 + myLength (xs)
```

I don't see how this works, what is 1 really being added too? How is the recursion returning something that can be added to? I don't get it.

And here we have this one:

```
splitLines [] = []
splitLines cs =
       let (pre, suf) = break isLineTerminator cs
       in  pre : case suf of 
                   ('\r':'\n':rest) -> splitLines rest
                   ('\r':rest)      -> splitLines rest
                   ('\n':rest)      -> splitLines rest
                   _                -> []

isLineTerminator c = c == '\r' || c == '\n'
```

How does this work, what is pre really being attached too? I don't see how the the result of the case expression is something that pre can be concatenated to. Maybe I just need someone to explain the evaluation of these functions in details. I must be missing something very vital.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I know, it was a copy-paste fail. Sorry.

EDIT 2: It seems my confusion was with what these functions were actually /returning/ I have it all worked out now. Thanks for the answers guys, it finally clicked! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for the first one, it's a very basic way of recursion. However, it seems to be missing a part:

```
myLength [] = 0
```

It works by scaling off one element at the time from the list and adding one to the result. To visualise, consider the call

```
myLength [1,2,3]
```

which will evaluate to:

```
1 + myLength [2,3]
1 + 1 + myLength [3]
1 + 1 + 1 + myLength []
1 + 1 + 1 + 0
```

which is 3.

As for the second one, well, you have already split the string at the next line break into two parts: pre and suf. Now, suf will start with either a \n, or a \r, or a \r\n. We want to remove these. So we use pattern matching. See how the rest variable is essentially the suf variable minus the initial line break character(s).

So we have pre, which is the first line, and rest, which is the rest of the text. So in order to continue splitting rest into lines we call splitLines on it recursively and concatenate the result to pre.

To visualize, say you have the string "foo\nbar\r\nbaz".

So, when calling, the result will be:

```
[ pre => foo, suf => \nbar\r\nbaz, rest => bar\r\n\baz ]
foo : splitLines bar\r\nbaz
```

then splitLines is called again, and the result is expanded into:

```
[ pre => bar, suf => \r\nbaz, rest = baz ]
foo : bar : splitLines baz
```

then once again:

```
[ pre => baz, suf => [], rest = [] ]
foo : bar : baz
```

which is the final result.

Comment: I understand how this works, but now I'm lost as to why this works. The result is either another recursive call, or an empty list. Essentially, it looks like pre is getting concatenated to pre every recur, but the case expression isn't returning pre. Confusing.

Comment: Actually after reading it again, it looks like pre is getting concatenated to the argument to splitLines, not the result. I'm just not sure how this is returning anything more than a recursive call which will eventually return []. I guess I don't understand recursion as much as I thought I did :\

Comment: When I look at the function, the case expression looks like it's returning the result of a recursive call which is the result of a recursive call which is the result of a recursive call, and so on until it returns []. I don't see how rest is being concatenated to pre in this situation.

Comment: That happens in the line "in  pre : case suf of", by the : operator.

Comment: So, pre is getting concatenated to pre every recur? But how, the recursion is returning a recursion or an empty list, how is this possible?

Comment: Oh boy, it just clicked. The pre : and everything after is the same expression. It's just like the myLength example. I understand now, exactly what the function is returning. I'm an idiot, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: With the speed at which Haskell questions are answered thoroughly and completely I don't think you need to apologize.  You clearly thought about this for a while and were just missing a piece.  Asking for another pair of eyes to point out where you've gone off the rails isn't a bad thing at all.

One technique that I find helpful with Haskell confusion like this is to look very carefully at the type signature of any function or expression that I don't get.  It's much more helpful in Haskell than in any other language I've used.

Comment: Oh, and you can ask ghci for the type of an expression by using `:t <expression>`

Answer (score 4):

I think the definition of `myLength` misses the case where the list is empty:

```
myLength [] = 0
myLength (x:xs) = 1 + myLength (xs)
```

With this definition, the `myLength` of an empty list is 0. The `(x:xs)` patten unpacks a list into the first item, `a`, and a list with the rest of the items, `xs`. If the list has one item, then `xs` is an empty list, so the result is 1 + 0. And so on.

Recursion is easiest to understand when you look at the base case first, and then see how each level of recursion builds on the result. (The base case is the case where the function does not call itself. If a recursive function doesn't have a base case, the output will be infinite.)

In the second example, the base case (the last case in the case-statment) is also an empty list. So pre will always be appended to a list, which will yield a new, longer, list.

Answer (score 2):

Re: `myLength (x:xs) = 1 + myLength (xs)` -- this is "half" of the definition of `myLength`, it says, by pattern match, that *if* the argument has a head and a tail, then the result is one more than the recursive tail call on the tail -- there needs to be another half to say that the result is 0 when the argument cannot match `x:xs`, i.e., when the argument is an empty list.

In the second case, the possibility of different patterns matching is just made a bit more epxlicit via `case`.

BTW, laziness is not a key issue here -- ML, with eager evaluation but pattern matching much like Haskell, would work very similarly. Looks like pattern matching is what you really need to brush up about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have pattern matching down packed, and I'm doing pretty well on recursion. My mistake was in what these functions were actually /returning/.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the first example should be like this (**edit:** it looks like you fixed it now):

```
myLength []     = 0
myLength (x:xs) = 1 + myLength (xs)
```

It works like this: say I give it a list with three items, it returns one plus the length of the tail (which is one plus the length of the tail (which is one plus the length of the tail, (which is `[]` at this point), which is 1), which is w), which is 3 (the final answer). Maybe nested parenthesis will help you understand it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is instructive to look at what the type signatures of the functions would be. They could be:

```
myLength :: [a] -> Int
```

In `myLength`, 1 is being added to the result of the recursive call to `myLength`, which is an `Int`, which in turn results in an `Int`.

```
splitLines :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
```

In `splitLines`, `pre` (a `[Char]`) is being prepended to the result of the case statement, which, from looking at the cases, is either the result of a recursive call to `splitLines`, which is `[[Char]]`; or an empty list. In both cases, prepending `pre` (a `[Char]`) will result in a `[[Char]]` in turn.

Comment: Okay, I understand the myLength example. But in the book it says that the second argument to : (pre :) is the result of the case expression, but the result of the case expression is either an empty list (which I get) or a recursive call to splitLines, how is pre being added to anything? I'm trying to work this out in my mind. Sorry for being an idiot. :\

Comment: More, I suppose what I'm asking, is how is a recursive call to splitLines, resulting in [[Char]]?

Comment: Well, you know that (:) is the "cons" operator, right; it takes an element and a list and returns a list with that element prepended to the other list. So (:) has type "a -> [a] -> [a]". So since pre has type [Char], the result of splitLines has type [[Char]].